# Hibernate DateCreated, DateModified columns from DB not VM(App)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, timestamp

Using Hibernate 3.5.1 and MSSQL 2008

Hi trying to implement the typical DateCreated and DateModified columns. The issue I have is that the time must be set from the DB not the application.

For DateCreated I can set the property to generated = always and set a default constraint (yes that reads right damn MS) on MS SQL 2008 to a default value of GetDate()

How would I go about it for DateModified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For DateCreated I can set the property to `generated = always` and set a default constraint (yes that reads right damn MS) on MS SQL 2008 to a default value of GetDate()

Well, you should actually use `generated = insert` for the creation date, it is not supposed to change upon subsequent updates and this will save an additional select for this column during updates.

> How would I go about it for DateModified?

And this is where you should use `generated = always` (and a trigger on the database side).

Here is what the reference documentation writes about them:

> #### [5.6. Generated properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated)
>
> Generated properties are properties
>   that have their values generated by
>   the database. Typically, Hibernate
>   applications needed to refresh objects
>   that contain any properties for which
>   the database was generating values.
>   Marking properties as generated,
>   however, lets the application delegate
>   this responsibility to Hibernate. When
>   Hibernate issues an SQL INSERT or
>   UPDATE for an entity that has defined
>   generated properties, it immediately
>   issues a select afterwards to retrieve
>   the generated values.
>
> Properties marked as generated must
>   additionally be non-insertable and
>   non-updateable. Only versions,
>   timestamps, and simple properties, can
>   be marked as generated.
>
> - `never`: (the default): the given property value is not generated within
>     the database.
> - `insert`: the given property value is generated on insert, but is not
>     regenerated on subsequent updates.
>     Properties like created-date fall into
>     this category. Even though version and
>     timestamp properties can be marked as
>     generated, this option is not
>     available.
> - `always`: the property value is generated both on insert and on
>     update.

Comment: Triggers are the devil in MSSQL so there has to be another way? Maybe a formula on the column?

Comment: @user432024 I don't know why triggers are particularly evil with MSSQL but... `The issue I have is that the time must be set from the DB not the application` I don't know how to do that without a trigger for the `DateModified` *if* you want to do it on the database side.

Comment: How about? formula="arbitrary SQL expression" http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property or timestamp properties?

Comment: @user432024 Formula properties are not persisted AFAIK.

Comment: I'm thinking of using custom sql. Fortunately the dates are only required for admin auditing so I technically don't need to bring back the generated value to the app.